# How can I control two ceiling fans and lights with one single pole switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I have two ceiling fans with two aftermarket light kits installed, all controlled from one single pole switch. So when switch is flipped, both fans and lights turn on or off at the same time. Only way to individually control each ceililng fan is to manually pull the chains. Is it possible to control the lights and fans separately using one single pole switch (switch that has fan/light controls)?

FYI - There is currently only a single black wire going from the breaker, to the switch, to the ceiling fans. I'm guessing some sort of canopy module would be needed? Is it possible to control the lights via the switch, but the ceiling fans via a remote system?

Comment: If you're willing to go the remote route why not just get a remote that does both lights & fans?

Answer (score 2):

The only product that I know of that will do what you want is the [Lutron Maestro Light/Fan control](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/033102a.pdf).  This product consists of a switch and canopy module.  The switch will digitally talk to the canopy module over the single ungrounded wire and control lights/fan separately.  The kits are one switch and one module but the switch can talk to 4 modules at once.

Comment: Depending on your needs -- the [Functional Devices FL101](http://www.functionaldevices.com/lighting-controls/display.php?model=FL101) can provide some control over a light/fan combo from an ordinary switch, but without any support for dimming or multi-speed fans.

Answer (score 0):

You could install remote modules in each fixture, however, since there's only a single ungrounded conductor your options are limited.

The easiest option might be to install the remote modules, and allow them to completely control each fixture. In this setup, the wall switch will turn everything on and off as before. But when the switch is on, the remotes will allow you to control the lights and fans independently.